# In EXCEL, how do I append data to other sheets when a new data is given to the master data sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, database, dynamic, append

In excel, I'm trying to build an account book where I only add the data once to the master list which will then sort and append the data to other sheets that represent different categories.

This is something that I want to do. I add all the information for a transaction (could be an income or expenditure) to sheet 1 (the master list). The information added will include the date, amount, payment method, and a key (more like a category). When this information is added, depending on the key, the given data will also be added to another sheet. For example, let's say I bought an apple from a grocery store. Then I'll add the following in a row into the master list

```
Date        Amount  Payment Method  Key 
01/01/2023  $1      credit card     Grocery store
```

When I add this to the master list, I want this to be added to another sheet named "Expenditure" and use the Key to label it as "Grocery". If I add income data to the master list, I want the same data to be added to the sheet named "Income". Duplicates should be allowed. I am aware that I can filter the master list to view things in different categories but I'd like to actually sort them and keep them in different sheets that are dynamic.

Comment: I often just link a block of cells - any addition to the master block appears in the linked block. Or you could do an if() and pick up relevant items based on  the category. Also check out the database functions in Excel - often start with "d".

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you can use `FILTER`-function on the sheets

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, for a similar purpose:

1. Power Query (which is available for Excel 2016 or later).
   To create depended sheets(query-tables) from the Master Sheet.
   Afetr adding new items in the Master Sheet, refresh the query to update the depending sheets(tables).
2. (Depends if lock/uplock of workbook needed) VBA for auto-refreshing to append/sort in the dependent sheet and lock/unlock WB/WS.
3. Dublicates are allowed (row number is the unique key).

My scenario:
For preparing COGS for 100+ stores(files).
Opening sheet is the Master where updates are allowed. It contains the list of all items with their SKU/Codes.
The dependent sheets (Purchase, internal transfers, wastages, Ending, COGS) are queries from the Master Sheet.
After adding new items, you just need to Refresh the query, new items are added  to the followings sheets.

My suggestion, you can use Power Query which is very user friendly/efficient and little VBA or not, depends if you need locking the sheets/book.